# Make iPhone app available on both iTunes and Cydia

Tags: iphone, app-store, jailbreak, cydia

What are the ramifications of posting an iphone app on both Cydia and iTunes? Does Apple look fondly at that idea? An precedents?

The reason I ask is that I have a very interesting app which might have some parts disallowed by Apple. I still want (some) people to have access to those parts (call it value-added), so I wanted to release the unrated app on cydia. (No it's not porn)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the SDK Agreement it specifically says that you won't add your application to another store, if you do, Apple can ban your itunesconnect account without warning.
Just prey they don't find your application on Cydia.

I guess you could do your application with a slightly different UI, and without the editor name, they would not have any proof to ban you.

Comment: Even a different name would probably do the trick.  I highly doubt they're going to go through both stores looking for dupe apps with different names.

Comment: @Seanny94 : Sorry ;-) @dc : Yeah, but I guess he wants for his application to be known as well on AppStore than cydia... But yeah that's the ultimate tip not to be ban, sure...

Answer (score 0):

One example that they're probably not enforcing this too strictly, can be found in the [Siphon](http://code.google.com/p/siphon/wiki/Submission) app.

Siphon is a popular, open source VoIP app, that the developer has been trying to get in the app store for forever. They haven't accepted the app, but the availability of the app in the official app-store was never mentioned, and they haven't banned his account either.